# Finding the 3rd occurence of a phrase in a string with regex

Tags: regex

I have a string like so:

`group[129][1][person][0][name]`

I have my regex currently at `\[\d+\]` which will match `[129]`, `[1]`, and `[0]`.

However, I want it to only match the third occurence `[0]`. I can't find anything on this. How do I do that?

Comment: are you missing a language tag?

Comment: Put it in a capture group and get the third occurrence? See an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/uE0vM5/5)

Comment: @XaviLópez How do you get the 3rd occurence from a capture group?

Comment: Depends on the language/regex tool/library you're using. Should be documented.

Comment: I'm testing on this site if that helps: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Similar to [Replace nth occurrence of string](//stackoverflow.com/q/35499498)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply include all three in your regex:

```
\d+\D+\d+\D+(\d+)
```

The capture group will capture the third set of digits.  Note that `\D` matches anything that is not a digit.

You could also avoid repetition by expressing it with a repeated group:

```
(?:\d+\D+){2}(\d+)
```

If you want to *replace* the third occurence, use something like this:

```
s/(\d+\D+\d+\D+)\d+/${1}FOO/;
```

This will replace the third set of digits with the word "FOO".  Using Perl syntax here, since you haven't specified the language.

Comment: Then how would I replace the last digit easily?

Comment: @RyanHipkiss edited. It would have been good to mention that in the first place in your question.

Comment: I'd accept the answer, but this matches the whole string. I only want to match the third occurrence.

Comment: @RyanHipkiss this is the most straightforward solution: match the whole string and include the portion you want to stay the same in your replacement pattern.  To have *only* the third occurrence be part of the match would require a variable-length lookbehind pattern, which is not supported by most regex engines.